# Logo needs to be updated on the Network Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I assume this is something that is in the plan to eventually implement, I'm just making sure it wasn't overlooked. The logo on the Network Profile is still showing the beta logo instead of the new piano keys one.

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDN was serving stale images - we purged that, but some proxy servers might still be serving those.

Try a hard refresh on the page (Ctrl + F5 / Apple key + F5).